# Cut function in R to account for reoccurring data

Tags: r

Say I have a range of data indicating the ages of individuals in years. Such that

```
ages <- sample(40:80, 30, replace = F)
```

Now I want to plot (boxplot) against another variable ~ say weight

But I want to cut the ages samples into the following catergories <50, >50, >60. >70.
So that an individuals weight, who is 66, will be used for both the >50 and >60 plots

My understanding is I use the `cut` command

```
age.category <- cut(ages, breaks = c(40, 50, 60, 70, 80) ........)
```

But how do I format to accounnt for repeated data, when I want

```
labels = c("x < 50", "x > 50", "x > 60", "x > 70")
```

Comment: `cut` will do a 1:1 mapping of value to group. It will not allow one value to be in two categories. Factors also only allow one category per observation. You cannot have one observation call into two categories. You would need two observations.

Comment: `cut(ages, breaks = c(40, 50, 60, 70, 80), right = F)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg no because "x < 50" + "x > 50" = 30

Comment: If you want to have only one plot, create multiple observations (i.e., rows) for "ambiguous" individuals (Personally I find this bad practice. Having some individuals occur in the same plot twice and others once? Don't...). If you want to have multiple plots, create one column per plot, for example one for a categorization <50, <60... 70+ and one for <40, <50... 60+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative "multicut" function which would allow you to specify arbitrary breaks. This will repeat values, once for each group that value appears. So if you had "64" it would output both `64, "x>50"` and `64, "x>60"`.

```
#sample data
set.seed(15)
ages <- sample(40:80, 30, replace = F)
weights <- 100 + ages*.2 + rnorm(30, 0 , 20)

#custom breaks
#named list, names-categories, values = 2-vector with min/max
breaks<-list(
   "x<50" =c(-Inf, 50),
   "x>50" =c(50, Inf),
   "x>60" = c(60, Inf),
   "x>70" = c(70, Inf)
)
```

Now we define the main helper function `multicut`

```
multicut <- function(x, breaks, vals=x, left.closed=TRUE, right.closed=FALSE, 
  x.name=if(missing(vals)) deparse(substitute(x)) else deparse(substitute(vals)),
  group.name="group") {

    unrowname <- function(x) {rownames(x)<-NULL; x}
    if (is.data.frame(vals)) {
        if(missing(x.name)) x.name<-names(vals)
        vals = Map(unrowname, split(vals, 1:nrow(vals)))
    }
    stopifnot(length(vals) == length(x))
    grp <- lapply(x, function(x) {
        mapply(function(z, br,l,r) {
            left<-if (l) z>=br[1] else z>br[1]
            right<-if (r) z<=br[2] else z<br[2]
            left & right
        }, x, breaks, left.closed, right.closed)
    })
    df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
        Map(cbind.data.frame,  
        g=lapply(grp, function(z) if(any(z)) names(breaks)[z] else NA),
        x=vals))
    df[[1]] <- factor(df[[1]], levels=names(breaks))
    names(df) <- c(group.name, x.name)
    df
}
```

Now we use it on the sample data

```
dd <- multicut(ages, breaks, weights)
boxplot(weights~group, dd)
```

The three important parameters to `multicut` are `x` which contains the values you use to wish for categorization, `breaks` which is the named list of min/max values for each group, and optionally `vals` which is either a vector or data.frame you want to split based on `x` and `breaks`. Here we want to use `age` to split up the `weights`.

[image]

Comment: Can you help me understand the `weights` parameter in your answer? I do understand that it assigns a weight to each individual (element in `ages`) but not sure I understand why this is good. I understood the question as simply asking to put a person of age x into all categories that are greater than x not just one and thereby giving this person a weight according to the number of categories/groups it is in. I don't fully understand your function and would be happy about enlightenment :)

Comment: @beginneR, I'm going off the OP's statement "I want to plot [age] against another variable ~ say weight". So i'm assuming each person has an age and weight (in pounds or kilograms). So you can split the ages into groups, but you also may want to split the weights into groups depending on ages. Thus I added the `vals=` parameter so you can split values other than age, based on age. Does that make more sense? I can see how the term "weight" might have been misleading.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Certainly makes more sense now - and I was thinking of a different kind of "weight". +1

Comment: full of class @MrFlick. You are a genius and thank you immensely

Comment: Also, something like `boxplot(lapply(breaks, function(x) weights[!is.na(cut(ages, x))]))` seems to work and, perhaps, manipulate arguments to `cut` accordingly.